# The POM for hibernate:hibernate3:jar:3.2.3.GA is missing,

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I have this error intalling a maven project:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringExample 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for hibernate:hibernate3:jar:3.2.3.GA is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.326 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-17T20:57:54+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SpringExample: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mkyong.common:SpringExample:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find hibernate:hibernate3:jar:3.2.3.GA in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

But I have no idea but to do to fix it !   I've tried all the options !

[image]